# Updating manual measure via REST API sets updated date to 1970

Tags: sonarqube

I was just looking to update a manual measure in SonarQube via the REST API, and when I send the call it does succeed, however the updated_at date now seems to be in 1970.  Querying the API using:

```
> curl http://server:9000/api/manual_measures?resource=resource1&metric=java_version
```

Gives the response

```
 [{"id":1,"metric":"java_version","resource":"resource1","text":
 "1.8","created_at":"2015-08-14T08:58:18+1200","updated_at":"1970-01-18T03:51:52+
 1200","login":"user","username":"username"}]
```

And then running an update:

```
curl -u username:password -d "resource=resource1&metric=java_version&text=1.8" http://server:9000/api/manual_measures
```

Gives the result

```
[{"id":1,"metric":"java_version","resource":"resource1","text":
"1.8","created_at":"2015-08-14T08:58:18+1200","updated_at":"1970-01-18T04:06:03+1200",
"login":"user","username":"username"}]
```

Is this expected behaviour?  Is there some config or setting that covers the date used here?

I had created the measure through the UI beforehand.

We're using SonarQube 5.1.1

Thanks

Comment: specifying the version of SonarQube is a prerequirement to get help

Comment: Sorry - wasn't great detail in the question - I've updated it

Comment: can you provide a reproducing request updating the manual measure and precise how you query the API to get the response with the incorrect date?

Comment: Added more detail to the question